# Overriding behavior in bootstrap.js for dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

We're using Bootstrap 3 for UI components. In bootstrap.js, there's a `Dropdown.prototype.keydown` function (see http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.js) that we would like to customize behavior of. The function currently only supports the up/down keys and escape. We'd like to add support for left/right keys because we've added support for nested dropdowns to bootstrap.

Without editing the actual bootstrap.js (not an option in this case), I don't see a way to override this behavior in `Dropdown.prototype.keydown` or customize it. Is there a pattern for doing this, without editing bootstrap.js itself?

So far the best I've come up with is adding my own event handler:

```
$(document).on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', '[data-toggle=dropdown]' + ', [role=menu]', function (e) {
    alert('dfsa');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by copying the bootstrap source and editing it to only handle right and left keycodes, since up and down are already bound. The key changes are lines 54, 78, and 79 here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js

Right acts as down, while left acts as up.

Im sure you could unbind them and handle them all with your own function, but this is the way I got it to work.

```
!function() {
  function getParent($this) {
    var selector = $this.attr('data-target')

    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && /#[A-Za-z]/.test(selector) && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') //strip for ie7
    }

    var $parent = selector && $(selector)

    return $parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent()
  }  

 var newDropdownFunction = function (e) {
    if (!/(37|39|27)/.test(e.keyCode)) return

    var $this = $(this)

    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()

    if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

    var $parent  = getParent($this)
    var isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

    if (!isActive || (isActive && e.keyCode == 27)) {
      if (e.which == 27) $parent.find(toggle).trigger('focus')
      return $this.trigger('click')
    }

    var desc = ' li:not(.divider):visible a'
    var $items = $parent.find('[role="menu"]' + desc + ', [role="listbox"]' + desc)

    if (!$items.length) return

    var index = $items.index($items.filter(':focus'))

    if ((e.keyCode == 37) && index > 0)                 index--                        // up
    if ((e.keyCode == 39) && index < $items.length - 1) index++                        // down
    if (!~index)                                      index = 0

    $items.eq(index).trigger('focus')
  }

  $(document).on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', '[data-toggle="dropdown"], [role="menu"], [role="listbox"]', newDropdownFunction)
}()
```

You can test it by going here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns and running it in console.

Comment: Also: If you can find a way to just edit the source, you should definitely take that route. :)